# How do I stop fragments from reloading WebView when selected from bottom navigation?

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, webview, android-viewpager

I need to stop each fragment from refreshing when selected from the bottom menu. There is loads of similar questions on here but being new to Android development I can't seem to get any to work. I think I know why it's happening (I believe I'm calling return new for each fragment) but unsure how to implement slightly different coding. In summary, I need each tab to load a WebView when first clicked then remain in that state until the user clicks a link within that view or closes the App.

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {

private BottomNavigationView mBottomNavigation;
private ViewPager viewPager;
private ViewPagerAdapter mViewPagerAdapter;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    loadFragment(new HomeFragment());
    mBottomNavigation = findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
    mBottomNavigation.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);

    viewPager = findViewById(R.id.view_pager);

    mViewPagerAdapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
    viewPager.setAdapter(mViewPagerAdapter);
    viewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(5);

}

private boolean loadFragment(Fragment fragment) {
    if (fragment != null) {
        FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        ft.replace(R.id.container, fragment);
        ft.commit();
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

@Override
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem menuItem) {
    Fragment fragment = null;
    switch (menuItem.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.navigation_news:
            fragment = new HomeFragment();
            break;
        case R.id.navigation_scheduled:
            fragment = new DashboardFragment();
            break;
        case R.id.navigation_LIVE:
            fragment = new NotificationsFragment();
            break;
        case R.id.navigation_results:
            fragment = new ResultsFragment();
            break;
        case R.id.navigation_help:
            fragment = new HelpFragment();
            break;
    }
    return loadFragment(fragment);
}}
```

ViewPagerAdapter.java

```
public class ViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {

public ViewPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm){
    super(fm);
}

@Override
public Fragment getItem(int position){
    switch (position) {
        case 0:
            return new HomeFragment();
        case 1:
            return new DashboardFragment();
        case 2:
            return new NotificationsFragment();
        case 3:
            return new ResultsFragment();
        case 4:
            return new HelpFragment();
    }
    return null;
    }
    @Override
public int getCount(){
    return 5;
}
```

}

activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/container"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingTop="0dp">

<androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/view_pager"/>

<com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
    android:id="@+id/nav_view"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="0dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="0dp"
    android:background="?android:attr/windowBackground"
    app:labelVisibilityMode="labeled"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:menu="@menu/bottom_nav_menu" />

/>

<fragment
    android:id="@+id/nav_host_fragment_activity_main"
    android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    app:defaultNavHost="true"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/nav_view"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.091"
    app:navGraph="@navigation/mobile_navigation"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="9dp" />

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

HomeFragment.java

```
public class HomeFragment extends Fragment {

private HomeViewModel HomeViewModel;
private FragmentHomeBinding binding;



@Override


public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);

    String url = "https://www.google.com";
    WebView view = (WebView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.webviewnews);
    view.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    view.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
    view.loadUrl(url);




    return rootView;
}

@Override
public void onDestroyView() {
    super.onDestroyView();
    binding = null;
}
}
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: What if try to use `FragmentPagerAdapter` instead?

Answer (score 1):

I guess that the problem here is the recreation of every fragment everytime `ViewPagerAdapter.getItem` gets called. Each time you click on an item, you create a new fragment. It won't just reload, it's actually a very new and fresh fragment without anything.

Try to lazily instantiate your fragments like below:

```
private HomeFragment homeFragment = null;

public Fragment getItem(int position){
    switch (position) {
        case 0:
            if(homeFragment == null) homeFragment = new HomeFragment();
            return homeFragment;
        // Other cases
```

This will not only help your problem, but also uses less memory and puts less pressure on GC.

Also, after your replacements, your fragments' `onResume` will be called (just in case if you need to do something you can do that in `onResume`)

Comment: Probably it would be better to use WeakReference.

Answer (score 0):

you are replacing fragment when loading fragment, so as soon as you will call replace fragment it will recreate fragment and onCreate will be called so in respect of replacing use add fragment that will not reload fragment again and again

Comment: Good point. Replace changed to add fragment but it's still reloading the WebView within each fragment.